# 'TypeError' object has no attribute ''

Tags: django, django-views, typeerror, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid with Django and I have two separate functions. One works using the SendGrid code (See below - Working Code) and then the other keeps getting the Error - 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'booking_message'.

I imagine the issue is something small and I keep missing it.

Appreciate any help I can get on this.

(Note - I have taken out the template id's, From and to email addresses and SendGrid API App id and just let '') I did not have time to use an environment variable to hide the keys before posting.

**Working code**

```
class ASPBookingsCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ASPBookingsForm
    model = ASPBookings
    template_name = "vistours/asp.html"

    def post(self, request):

        # Save the new booking to the database.
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ASPBookingsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print(request.POST)
                form.save()

                # Get the data for the emails.
                asp_data = ASPBookings.objects.all()
                asp_data.contact_name = request.POST['contact_name']
                asp_data.booking_email = request.POST['email']
                asp_data.booking_date = request.POST['booking_date']
                asp_data.booking_time = request.POST['booking_time']
                asp_data.program_type =request.POST['program_type']

                # Format Date and Time
                formatted_date = parse_date(asp_data.booking_date).strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
                print(formatted_date)

                # Add SendGrid Template ID's
                BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID = ''
                UPDATE_TEMPLATE_ID = ''

                # Send confirmation email of the booking.
               
                booking_message = Mail(from_email='',
                    to_emails=[asp_data.booking_email],
                    )
                    
                # Add Template ID to booking message.

                booking_message.template_id = BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID

                # Add Dynamic Data

                booking_message.dynamic_template_data = {

                    'contact_name': asp_data.contact_name,
                    'booking_date': formatted_date,
                    'booking_time': asp_data.booking_time,
                }

                # Send new booking alert to VIS Staff.
                message = Mail(from_email='',
                    to_emails='')
                    
                message.template_id = UPDATE_TEMPLATE_ID

                # Add Dynamic Data

                message.dynamic_template_data = {

                    'contact_name': asp_data.contact_name,
                    'booking_date': formatted_date,
                    'booking_time': asp_data.booking_time,
                    'program_type': asp_data.program_type,
                }


                # Send Email
                try:
                    sg = SendGridAPIClient('')
                    sg2 = SendGridAPIClient('')
                    response = sg.send(booking_message)
                    responses = sg2.send(message)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e.message)


            else:
                print(form.errors)
                form()
        return render(request, 'vistours/success.html')
```

**Code getting Type Error** **Error - 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'booking_message'.**

```
def confirm_booking(request, id, program_type):

    if program_type == 'asp':
        confirm_booking = ASPBookings.objects.get(id=id)
        confirm_booking.status = 'Confirmed'
        confirm_booking.save()

        
        # Format Date and Time
        formatted_date = confirm_booking.booking_date.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
        # print(formatted_date)

        # Add SendGrid Template ID's
        CONFIRMED_BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID = ''

        # Send confirmation email of the booking.
               
        booking_message = Mail(from_email='',
            to_emails=[confirm_booking.email])

        # Add Template ID to booking message.

        booking_message.template_id = CONFIRMED_BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID

        # Add Dynamic Data

        booking_message.dynamic_template_data = {

            'contact_name': confirm_booking.contact_name,
            'booking_date': confirm_booking.booking_date,
            'booking_time': confirm_booking.booking_time,
        }

        # Send Email
        try:
            sg = SendGridAPIClient('')
            response = sg.send(booking_message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.booking_message)

        
    elif program_type == 'bfbw':
        confirm_booking = BFBWBookings.objects.get(id=id)
        confirm_booking.status = 'Confirmed'
        confirm_booking.save()


        # # Format Date and Time
        # formatted_date = parse_date(confirm_booking.booking_date).strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
        # print(formatted_date)

        # Add SendGrid Template ID's
        BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID = ''
        

        # Send confirmation email of the booking.
               
        booking_message = Mail(from_email='',
            to_emails=[confirm_booking.email])
                    
        # Add Template ID to booking message.

        booking_message.template_id = BOOKING_TEMPLATE_ID

        # Add Dynamic Data

        booking_message.dynamic_template_data = {

            'contact_name': confirm_booking.contact_name,
            'booking_date': confirm_booking.booking_date,
            'booking_time': confirm_booking.booking_time,
        }

        # Send Email
        try:
            sg = SendGridAPIClient('')
            response = sg.send(booking_message)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e.booking_message)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: You're trying to print `e.booking_message` in your `except` blocks, the error most likely doesn't have this attribute?

Comment: Thanks Iain that was it. Once I changed it to print(e) it worked.

Comment: Out of interest I am trying to format the date confirm_booking.booking_date.strftime('%A %d %B %Y') but keep getting the message Object of type date is not JSON serializable when adding it to the  booking_message.dynamic_template_data. Would you know how to resolve this? I know this is out of the scope of the original question so no worries if I need to re post a new question.

Comment: You're only setting the `formatted_date` in the `booking_message.dynamic_template_data` in the first function (`post`) and not the second function (`confirm_booking`). Might that be your problem?

Comment: Meant to add I managed to resolve this other this. Thanks Philnash for the help I will look to close this issue off.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to print e.booking_message in your except blocks, the error most likely doesn't have this attribute? – Iain Shelvington Jun 25 at 4:37